Nextjs middleware exclude homepage from matcher
I'm checking user auth in the middleware and redirecting to a sign in page if not logged in. This works well but I want to exclude the middleware on the homepage which is the root of the site /. I tried many variations but nothing is working.
For example, my original matcher:
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
  ],
};

New:
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     * - root path (homepage)
     */
    "/((?!^$|^/$|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
  ],
};

It doesn't work. I can specify certain paths like "blog", "contact", etc and it works but not for the homepage.
I even tried explicitly adding '/'.
